# Can anyone please explain what's happening here with spread operator

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

The following code is giving me the output I wanted, But I need to understand more. Can anyone please explain what's happening here with spread operator,

```
 const myObject = {
      "employeeid": "160915848",
      "firstName": "tet",
      "lastName": "test",
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "country": "Brasil",
      "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "currentOrganization": "test",
      "salary": "1234567"
    };
    const {otherIndustry,currentOrganization, ...otherIndustry2} = myObject;
    console.log(otherIndustry2);

Output:

{
  "employeeid": "160915848",
  "firstName": "tet",
  "lastName": "test",
  "email": "test@email.com",
  "country": "Brasil",
  "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "salary": "1234567"
};
```

Comment: This doesn't look like R code to me, so why did you use the `[spread]` tag?  (Hint: *read the tag wiki!*)

Comment: Assume the json data return from db. Here I want to remove two columns or I don't want the properties(otherIndustry, currentOrganization).

Comment: So you didn't take the hint.  I have fixed the tag for you and added a `[javascript]` so that people who can answer are more likely to notice the question.  Note: correct tagging it important if you want answers.  (And if you don't want answers ... you shouldn't be asking.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an object destructuring assignment question.

So this line `const {otherIndustry,currentOrganization, ...otherIndustry2} = myObject;` is an object destructuring statement, it first assigns the value of `otherIndustry` and `currentOrganization` to the variables under the same name, for the rest of the values, they are all assigned as an object to `otherIndustry2`

Reference: [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thank you so much for the simple and clear answer.